# How to get 'Handwriting Keyboard' drawings on iOS/Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, sdk, keyboard

I know most of you using keyboad would be enough for text inputs, but not for asian.
We use handwriting keyboard a lot, while our words are mostly 'pictures'.
And iOS SDK was written in English, that I guess here's the best place to ask if there's any solution to:

How to get the drawing from Handwring Keyboard? any chance?

further more, I'll explain a bit more on the question below...

please see image link example here:
http://nevermai.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/maibelle-mountain.png

the image above, explains handwriting keyboard inputs for character 'mountain' in Chinese.
center area is a drawing, and right side bar suggests relevant characters (that the green circled character is what we wanted and just tap on it, to complete text input)

This is how Asians input their own language on iPhone.

My question again, is how to get the center area's drawing before the character has been selected (because once the character has been selected, it wash out the drawing area)? Would there be any chance to store this drawing to somewhere and re-use it, as a picture/image? Or any other possible way in SDK to achieve this?

Comment: gesture can help in drawing portion. and you can also save the gesture which will help you in finding your words.

Comment: have you considered having the app take a screenshot and then you only use the specific region?